# Significado de "tener una paja para la vida"

Tags: expresiones, significado, hispanoamérica, argentina

En una página de Facebook, [La  gente anda diciendo](https://www.facebook.com/LaGenteAndaDiciendo), se divulgan frases divertidas o interesantes que se escuchan por la calle. [Una de esas frases](https://www.facebook.com/LaGenteAndaDiciendo/photos/a.449354605109142.105530.446303612080908/993697310674866/?type=1&theater) me capturó la atención:

> Son dos polos opuestos. Él tiene una paja para la vida y ella quiere cambiar el mundo.

Aunque se pueda adivinar por lo contexto, ¿qué exactamente quiere decir "tener una paja para la vida"? ¿Es una jerga? Si lo es, ¿es exclusivamente argentina?

Comment: Nunca lo he oído ni leído. En [uno de los comentarios](https://www.facebook.com/LaGenteAndaDiciendo/photos/a.449354605109142.105530.446303612080908/993697310674866/?type=1&comment_id=993781073999823&offset=0&total_comments=670&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D) Axel Sanabria aclara que: `Paja = Vagancia (Hace todo sin ganas... o directamente no lo hace :P)`

Comment: Como giro idiomático, en Argentina, Latinoamérica, la expresión "paja mental" también puede hacer referencia a una situación de contenido sexual similar a "hacerse los ratones". Verbigracia: "Tengo una paja mental con fulana/o de tal".
Dicho a otra persona, es brindar un trato deningrante, "sos un pajero", aplica como "no te da la cabeza". Cada idioma es tan basto en sus expresiones callejeras...

Comment: Creo que el artículo _una_ (en _una paja_) se usa aquí para enfatizar. Se entiende mejor el texto sin esa palabra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Tener paja" [significa](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Tener%20paja.php)

> Tener desgano, no tener ganas de hacer nada.

Por lo que la frase del ejemplo significa "Él no tiene ganas de nada y ella quiere cambiar el mundo (lo que implica un montón de trabajo)".

Es una expresión argentina, aunque quizá sea entendida y usada en otros países de América latina (no así en España, donde se usaría un equivalente como "Ha nacido cansado" o similar, para expresar que alguien nunca tiene ganas de nada). Desde luego es jerga o lenguaje coloquial.

Se puede usar la expresión "tener paja" en otros contextos (por lo menos en España, no sé si esto es así en otros países latinoamericanos) para expresar que tiene "algo que sobra o carente de valor". Es la simplificación de la expresión "Mucha paja y poco trigo". Por ejemplo, puedes decir que un autor rellena su libro con mucha paja (el libro tiene *mucha paja*) para expresar que mete muchas cosas que no aportan demasiado con el simple fin de "engordar" el libro.

Hay otra expresión similar que es "tener una paja **mental**", que no implica tener cansancio o vaguedad, sino un lío o desorden "mental".

Comment: En Colombia, se usa la expresión `habla (pura o mucha) paja` la cual tiene un significado similar a la expresión `Mucha paja y poco trigo` de su respuesta.

Comment: Quiero advertir que la expresión "tener paja" o "me da paja" más que "jerga o lenguaje coloquial", es lenguaje juvenil vulgar (aunque muy "light"). Puesto que proviene del mote "pajero" (="que abusa de la masturbación"). No usarlo si no estamos seguros del contexto. http://etimologias.dechile.net/?paja

Answer (score 0):

en argentina, masturbarse es hacerse una paja. si te pajeas mucho supuestamente te cansas. de ahí el,,, tengo una paja, como que no Tenes ganas de hacer nada. asi se aplica a todo, me da paja hacer tal cosa.... me da paja poner mas ejemplos...